# How to use an SVG as a button HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been trying to get a an SVG to be usable as a button which will basically switch between Celsius and Fahrenheit. The trouble has been with using the SVG itself as the button. Ideally I want to have a hover effect where the whole SVG lights up, but I've sort of hit a wall now and cannot figure out for the life of me how to get this to work and why it looks so bad.

Could someone tell me what the heck I am doing wrong here?

Is it possible to have an SVG alone as a button and not have to go through all the work of making the button element transparent and stacking the two elements?

```css
.button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: blue solid;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.svg-icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="button">
              <svg
                class="svg-icon"
                role="img"
                width="10"
                height="10"
                fill="none"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M9.25 10.7917C10.0995 10.7917 10.7917 11.4839 10.7917 12.3333C10.7917 13.1828 10.0995 13.875 9.25 13.875C8.40054 13.875 7.70833 13.1828 7.70833 12.3333C7.70833 11.4839 8.40054 10.7917 9.25 10.7917ZM9.25 9.25C7.54646 9.25 6.16667 10.6298 6.16667 12.3333C6.16667 14.0369 7.54646 15.4167 9.25 15.4167C10.9535 15.4167 12.3333 14.0369 12.3333 12.3333C12.3333 10.6298 10.9535 9.25 9.25 9.25ZM27.7253 21.5047C27.585 23.4426 26.8697 24.9673 25.5793 26.0804C24.2905 27.1935 22.59 27.75 20.478 27.75C18.1701 27.75 16.354 26.973 15.0312 25.419C13.7085 23.865 13.0471 21.7313 13.0471 19.0195V17.9188C13.0471 16.1875 13.3524 14.6628 13.9613 13.3431C14.5718 12.025 15.4429 11.0121 16.5775 10.3076C17.7107 9.60304 19.0272 9.25 20.5273 9.25C22.6055 9.25 24.2782 9.80654 25.5485 10.9196C26.8188 12.0327 27.5511 13.5944 27.75 15.6063H24.0407C23.9498 14.4439 23.626 13.6006 23.0695 13.078C22.513 12.5538 21.6666 12.2933 20.5288 12.2933C19.2924 12.2933 18.3674 12.7373 17.7523 13.6222C17.1387 14.5086 16.8227 15.8838 16.8057 17.7461V19.1059C16.8057 21.0515 17.1002 22.4744 17.6891 23.3717C18.278 24.2705 19.2076 24.7191 20.478 24.7191C21.6234 24.7191 22.479 24.457 23.0433 23.9344C23.6075 23.4102 23.9313 22.6008 24.0145 21.5047H27.7253ZM18.5 3.08333C27.0007 3.08333 33.9167 9.99925 33.9167 18.5C33.9167 27.0007 27.0007 33.9167 18.5 33.9167C9.99925 33.9167 3.08333 27.0007 3.08333 18.5C3.08333 9.99925 9.99925 3.08333 18.5 3.08333ZM18.5 0C8.28337 0 0 8.28337 0 18.5C0 28.7166 8.28337 37 18.5 37C28.7166 37 37 28.7166 37 18.5C37 8.28337 28.7166 0 18.5 0Z"
                  fill="#F5F5F5"
                />
              </svg>
            </button>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-many-ways-to-change-an-svg-fill-on-hover-and-when-to-use-them/ Is this what you're looking for? Also, a button (by default) submits a form. So if you're just looking for the SVG to be _clickable_, and you're needing to use JavaScript to toggle F/C anyway, then you can take the `<button>` out of the equation and just add a click handler to the `svg` itself to trigger the toggle functionality.

Comment: Button functionality for an SVG is a matter of Javascript....but yes it is certainly possible.

Comment: But the first thing to do is remove the positioning from the SVG. It's just not necessary *inside* the button. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dypOgBw

Comment: Also i notice your SVG does not have a `viewbox`, that should really be there for proper centering

Comment: @Woundedstevenjones 
Thank you for the reply! I didn't realize that it would also take javascript to make it clickable. I mean I know the onclick handler, but I didn't even really think of doing that without a button (as silly as that is).

Thanks again for the reply! I'll try and get it working tonight!

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for the reply!
I didnt know about viewbox for this, but I will definitely give this a go!